# Codeigniter XML-RPC connecting to Odoo Domain Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-12

I'm developing a PHP API interface to get data from the Odoo 12 API on our local network for our intranet.

The `authenticate` method is working ok, so connection is well stablished.

I'm having trouble on the `search` method. Whatever I try to add as the last parameter, is giving me the same error from the API:

> AssertionError: Domains to normalize must have a 'domain' form: a list
>   or tuple of domain components

This is the PHP code I'm using for the request, using the XML-RPC library from CodeIgniter.

```
    $this->xmlrpc->server($this->url.$this->ep_object);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('execute_kw');

    $request = array(
        array($this->db, 'string'),
        array($this->user_id , 'int'),
        array($this->password, 'string'),
        array('res.partner', 'string'),
        array('search', 'string'),
        array(
          array(
            array(
              array('is_company', '=', true),
              array('customer', '=', true)
            )
          )
          , 'struct')   
    );
    $this->xmlrpc->request($request);

    if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
    {
            echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
    }
    else
    {
            $val = $this->xmlrpc->display_response();
            var_dump($val);
    }
```

The problem seems to be on the last parameter of the `$request` array. I've tried with an empty list, an `Array` with another `Array` inside, etc... always same error. That code above is trying to replicate the same code as on the API documentation, which is by far not the more detailed in the area:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#list-records

As far as I know it looks like the encoding made by the Codeigniter Library may be different, or I'm missing something.

Comment: Isn't that one array too much? Should be array(array(arrays)) and what is `'struct'` for?

Comment: Those are specific from the codeigniter library. First you need an array with (param, type). Then, the param type is an array of params, which first param is another array... That's when it comes the difficult part.

Comment: I don't mean the array around the parameters db, user_id and password, and so on. I mean those four nested arrays for the last parameter, which are the Odoo method's arguments.

Comment: That's the required structure by Odoo. Struct is used for associative arrays as I could read. Is hard to implement with this library, I'm thinking on going with a 3rd party one instead of CI default one.

Comment: Oh i see Odoo's examples are for the ripcord library. God i hate PHP ^^ Sorry i can't help you that much :/